# How to calculate the difference between values in a dictionary

Tags: python-3.x

I have a dictionary looks like this

```
time = {"0": 1552644000109, 
"1": 1552644000113, 
"2": 1552644000116, 
"3": 1552644000116, 
"4": 1552644000118, 
"5": 1552644000119, 
"6": 1552644000119, 
"7": 1552644000120, 
"8": 1552644000121, 
"9": 1552644000122, 
"10": 1552644000123, 
"11": 1552644000123, 
"12": 1552644000124}
```

I am trying to calculate the difference between 0-1 and 1-2 and 2-3 and so on.. in order to write another code that `if the difference is > x; do this`

Here is my code:

```
I converted the keys into integer 

inttime = {int(k):int(v) for k,v in time.items()}
for k,v in inttime.items():
        a=  inttime[k+1][0]-inttime[k][0]
        print(a)
```

Here is my error:

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: Remove the `[0]` from both places. `inttime[someNumber]` already returns said integer value (hence `int` is not subscriptable).

Comment: Done thank you ! the last k+1 becomes 13 and gives me error in the last loop. Any tricks to prevent it ?

Comment: `if k == len(inttime): break`?

Comment: if k == len(inttime)-1: break -- worked thank you

Comment: Yup, you got it.

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to solve problems as such is to zip together lists of values, when one of the lists is slightly shifted. Thus:

```
>>> values = list(time.values())
>>> shifted = values[1:]
>>> differences = [next_val - current for current, next_val in zip(values, shifted)]

>>> differences
[4, 3, 0, 2, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1]
```

Comment: Good solution. Make sure the values are sorted by key first.